# Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid when using Webpack 4

Tags: typescript, webpack

#### BLUF

I have an application with the following dependencies

```
ProjectX (web app)
    └ ProjectY (custom package)
        └ rc-tooltip@3.5.0
```

When bundling ProjetX with Webpack 1 everything worked without error. However, when upgraded to Webpack 4 the rc-tooltip component used in ProjectY throws the following runtime error:

> warning.js:33 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid --
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: object.

#### Details

Within ProjectY Tooltip is imported like so:

```
const Tooltip = require("rc-tooltip);

<div>
  <Tooltip all-my-props>
    my content
  </Tooltip>
</div>
```

Under Webpack 1 and 4 the creation of the rc-tooltip `Tooltip` initially appears to be the same:

```
React.createElement(Tooltip, my-props, my-childern):
```

However, inspecting Tooltip via the console reveals key differences.

Under Webpack 1:

```
> Tooltip
  ƒ Tooltip() {
    var _ref;
    var _temp, _this, _ret;
    (0, _classCallCheck3['default'])(this, Tooltip);
    for (var _len = arguments.length, args = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _…
```

Under Webpack 4:

```
> Tooltip
  {default: ƒ, __esModule: true}default: ƒ Tooltip()__esModule: true__proto__: Object
```

It appears that under Webpack 4 I am not receiving the properly
exported class. In fact, on the console I can create a new React
element without error via

```
React.createElement(Tooltip.default, my-props, my-childern):
```

Why would Webpack 4 alter how a package is expressed in my application?
Is this a configuration issue, what am I missing?

#### Webpack 4 Configuration

```
// webpack.common.js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/app/main.ts"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[hash].bundle.js",
    publicPath: "./",
    libraryTarget: "amd"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    noParse: [/html2canvas.js/],
    rules: [
      //typescript
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      },
      // css
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      },
      // images
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: "url-loader",
        query: { mimetype: "image/png" }
      },
      // fonts
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader:
          "url-loader?limit=10000&name=fa/[hash].[ext]&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=fa/[hash].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: [
    function(context, request, callback) {
      if (
        /^dojo/.test(request) ||
        /^dijit/.test(request) ||
        /^esri/.test(request)
      ) {
        return callback(null, "amd " + request);
      }
      callback();
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "index.ejs",
      inject: false
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ]
};

// webpack.dev.js
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the import syntax from

```
const Tooltip = require("rc-tooltip);
```

to

```
import Tooltip from "rc-tooltip";
```

> While this solution works I will not yet accept this answer as it does not explain why Webpack 4 produces incorrect output with the original import syntax.